# Sorting data and storing only top three results in variable: XSLT

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have a XML file say

```
<Nodes>
     <node>12</node>
     <node>244</node>
     <node>234</node>
     <node>45</node>
     <node>7</node>
     <node>112</node>
     <node>64</node>
     <node>3</node>
</Nodes>
```

All I want is, sort the data according to values in descending order, and store only top 3 results in to a variable.

Sorting of data has done using `<xsl:sort>`, but how to store top 3 results in a variable and also how to access this varible?

I want to display data for top three projects.
i.e.

```
  Value1=244
  Value2=234
  Value3=112
```

Please ask for any more information is required.

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `position()` function:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Nodes/node">
  <xsl:sort select="."/>
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 4">
      ...
      Value<xsl:value-of select="position() + 1"/>=<xsl:value-of select="."/>
      ...
  <xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thnks... I have used same approach.